# How to add persistence storage volumes to Traefik and cert-manager in a k3s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, persistence, traefik, volume, cert-manager

I used [nfs-subdir-external-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/tree/master/deploy) for the deployment of the nfs in k3s cluster. I also tested with the given `test-claim.yaml` and `test-pod.yaml` files which works fine.

Now, following [this](https://github.com/techno-tim/launchpad/tree/master/kubernetes/traefik-cert-manager) to deploy traefik and cert-manager. And I see no mention of the storage (persistent).

In traefik, I can see [from here (line 786)](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/values.yaml#L786) where it talks about persistence and [line 47](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/values.yaml#L47) and [line 236](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/values.yaml#L236) talk about volume. But I didn't get whether I need to claim (multiple claims for each config, certs, log, etc?) volume first (separately) and then just add the volume? or just need to provide details of storageclass under persistence (L786), rest will be taken care of automatically? Similarly for [cert-manager](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cert-manager/cert-manager)?